# a / b, but return 0 if b == 0

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I would like a division method that returns `a / b`, and `0` if `b` is `0`, and `nan` if at least one of `a` or `b` is `nan`, and that works for scalar and array inputs, i.e.,

```py
import numpy as np


def div(a, b):
    out = a / b
    # out[b == 0] = 0  TypeError: 'float' object does not support item assignment
    # out = np.nan_to_num(out, nan=0.0)
    return out


assert div(2, 1) == 2
assert np.all(div(np.array([2, 2]), np.array([1, 1])) == np.array([2, 2]))
assert np.isnan(div(np.nan, np.nan))
assert div(np.array(0), np.array(0)) == 0
```

`np.nan_to_num` almost does the trick, but I'd love to control the condition (`b == 0` vs `isnan`).

Comment: `a/b` already returns `nan` if either argument is `nan`; the only thing left to do is either test if `b == 0` explicitly, or catch the `ZeroDivisionError` raised by `a/b` when `b == 0`.

Comment: Ufunc like `np.divide` take a `where` parameter (which should be used along with the `out` parameter).  Handling scalars may be require a separate path, since most `numpy` methods return an array even if given scalars.

Comment: @hpaulj `divide`actually works perfectly, for scalars too. Would you like to promote the comment to an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about using `np.where` ?

```py
np.where(b==0, 0, a/b)
```

This assumes your inputs are numpy arrays, but you can handle the conversion easily before that.

Answer (score 2):

```py
import numpy as np


def div(a, b):
    if(not isinstance(a, np.ndarray)):
        return a*b and a/b
    else:
        a[b==0] = 0
        b[b==0] = 1
        return a/b


assert div(2, 1) == 2
assert np.all(div(np.array([2, 2]), np.array([1, 1])) == np.array([2, 2]))
assert np.isnan(div(np.nan, np.nan))
assert div(np.array(0), np.array(0)) == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just only calculate for slots where b is not 0.
This of course assumes [as in the question] that the inputs are arrays and not scalars

```
def div(a, b):
    out = np.zeros_like(a)
    out[b != 0] = a[b != 0] / b[b != 0]
    return out
```

to support scalar values add `a, b, = np.array(a), np.array(b)` as a first line.

Comment: @nico read to the end. 'To support scalar values...'

Answer (score -1):

If performance is not a concern, you could use [`vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).

As @chepner already pointed out, the `nan` case is already handled by `/`. So you just need to check if `b == 0`.

```
@np.vectorize
def div(a, b):
    return 0 if b == 0 else a / b
```

Comment: The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop. see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Comment: OP says nothing about performance. This is a simple documented solution. I agree it's not ideal if performance is a concern, but it is a valid answer.

Comment: It is valid. I believe it should be discouraged, given other simple solutions. Future readers should be aware and select accordingly.